# is happybase 1.1.0 api compatible with Hbase2.1.2? I am getting transport exception

Tags: python, hbase, happybase

I try to use `happpybase 1.1.0` with `hbase2.X.X` but I am getting transport exception. I have set transport and protocol parameter as "framed" and "compat" in happybase and also set while starting thrift services.

> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/happybase/table.py", line
>   402, in scan self.name, scan, {}) File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/thriftpy/thrift.py", line 198,
>   in _req return self._recv(_api) File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/thriftpy/thrift.py", line 210,
>   in _recv fname, mtype, rseqid = self._iprot.read_message_begin() File
>   "thriftpy/protocol/cybin/cybin.pyx", line 429, in
>   cybin.TCyBinaryProtocol.read_message_begin
>   (thriftpy/protocol/cybin/cybin.c:6325)
>
> File "thriftpy/protocol/cybin/cybin.pyx", line 60, in cybin.read_i32
>   (thriftpy/protocol/cybin/cybin.c:1546)
>
> File "thriftpy/transport/buffered/cybuffered.pyx", line 65, in
>   thriftpy.transport.buffered.cybuffered.TCyBufferedTransport.c_read
>   (thriftpy/transport/buffered/cybuffered.c:1881)
>
> File "thriftpy/transport/buffered/cybuffered.pyx", line 69, in
>   thriftpy.transport.buffered.cybuffered.TCyBufferedTransport.read_trans
>   (thriftpy/transport/buffered/cybuffered.c:1948)
>
> File "thriftpy/transport/cybase.pyx", line 61, in
>   thriftpy.transport.cybase.TCyBuffer.read_trans
>   (thriftpy/transport/cybase.c:1472)
>
> File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/thriftpy/transport/socket.py",
>   line 125, in read message='TSocket read 0 bytes')
>   thriftpy.transport.TTransportException: TTransportException(type=4,
>   message='TSocket read 0 bytes')

Comment: Is Thrift server running?

Comment: yes. I started Hbase in-built thrift service with the following command  ./hbase-daemon.sh start thrift -hsha

Comment: sorry it's due to my internal network problem causes this error. It works fine with default settings provided in happybase.